# Is todonotes compatible with twocolumn?

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, todonotes

I'd really like to have my `tikz` `\todo` notes in my `twocolumn` document. When writing on the right column it's fine, but the left column drives it crazy.

I tried to fiddle with the textwidth option but to no avil (e.g. `textwidth=\columnwidth-ε` and the like). Is there a solution?

p.s. This code goes wrong:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
This is\todo{correct typos} some pretty cool text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that other than _qubyte_'s answer, you can also simply switch to inline notes if you're not worried about pushing your actual text content around. This works by adding the line `\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}` to your preamble ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219363)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following in the preamble:

```
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
```

This allows todo notes to sit further within the margin. This works for me when added to your MWE.

Comment: wow, that actually worked. but can I ask you a question? I'm using the fullpage package as well and this command didn't seem to clash with it: how is that possible?

Comment: By default `fullpage` sets all margins to 1 inch. This is slightly larger than the parwidth defined above, so the two don't clash. :)

Comment: ah, good to know. My next mission will be to use the geometry package instead of fullpage. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: This tip can also be found in the official documentation of todonotes on page 10 in the PDF: https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes