# Latex todonotes package set default to inline

Tags: inline, todonotes

Is it possible to set the default style of todo notes by the latex *todonotes* package to inline to avoid mentioning inline everytime?

I imported the package into my latex document like this:

```
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
```

and used it in the document like this:

```
\todo[inline]{New TODO comment}
```

Comment: The following, `\let\svtodo\todo\renewcommand\todo[1]{\svtodo[inline]{#1}}`, will allow you to do it by redefining the existing macro, but will not allow for any optional arguments.

Comment: `\newcommand{\todoin}[2][]{\todo[inline,#1]{#2}}`. Similar to Johannes_B solution but with optional arguments. More o less similar example is shown in `todonotes` documentation, page 15.

Comment: `\setuptodonotes{inline}` in my preamble does it for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Patching it into the original code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
%\tracingxpatches%for debugging
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@todo}{\setkeys{todonotes}{#1}}{\setkeys{todonotes}{inline,#1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{This should be inline}
\blindtext\todo[color=blue!20!white]{Is this blue?}
\end{document}
```

[image: michaTodoDefault]

Advantage: You can still use any optional argument.

Comment: Thanks for this quick response. You solved my problem. This will save me a lot of typing in future.

Comment: How do I use a non-inline todo once I have changed the default?

Answer (score 41):

You can add more keys to the preset list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,prependcaption,textsize=tiny]{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\presetkeys%
    {todonotes}%
    {inline,backgroundcolor=yellow}{}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\todo{This should be inline}
\blindtext\todo[color=blue!20!white]{Is this blue?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To simplify this answer, add one line after the `usepackage`: `\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}`. Works well for me.

Answer (score 21):

In newer versions of `todonotes` you can use `\setuptodonotes` to set default options.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\setuptodonotes{inline}

\begin{document}

Some text.\todo{Improve text.}

\end{document}
```